# Taking encrypted devices across borders

Tags: encryption, linux, privacy, disk-encryption, government

I am moving to a country where the government can compel you to reveal passwords for your devices at the border, rendering the full disk encryption on my linux laptop useless.

Other than uploading everything to the cloud, what else can I do to take my data with me safely?

Ideally, I would like a solution which preserves the software and settings that are installed on my laptop.

Comment: Shipping the computer by express courier ahead of your visit ? Not cheap or practical though. But since you say "moving" I am assuming you are relocating to that country, and you may have already planned to ship some furniture of other belongings anyway.

Comment: What happens if you forget your password?

Comment: [VeraCrypt Hiddien Volume](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/81020/18298)? Dropbox, Google Drive?

Answer (score -1):

you can create a tricky webapp in your localhost, with your own database that obfuscates your local data and then shows raw data. but you can disable your app, using a rest request in another online server for receiving specific response, after that starting the, deobfuscate or decrypting.
in this scenario, you can give your all harddisk encrypted passwords. because all of logic your deobfuscation, in your app, and your app, you can controlling in online server with editing response. and you can compile your app and delete source from your laptop.